# Why is pop.gmail.com network is unreachable?

Tags: networking, python, pop3, gmail

I am trying to connect to `pop.gmail.com` using the following python script, running as root:

```
import poplib
pop_conn = poplib.POP3_SSL('pop.gmail.com', 995)
```

and after minutes of waiting I finally see:

```
socket.error: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable
```

Is there really a problem? Am I doing something wrong? Are the problems related to firewall etc on my side -> How to find out in this case? How can I connect to `pop` my emails?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there really a problem?

Yes, the network is unreachable.

> Am I doing something wrong?

Your code runs without error on my system.

> Are the problems related to firewall etc on my side -> How to find out in this case?

This could be caused by a number of things. You will need to inspect the firewall rules on your system and take appropriate action. If your system isn't blocking access then it could be an upstream firewall or it could be a network problem between you and the remote host (try to ping it, it responds for me) ...